# Discrepancy in HTML element position between ipod and xcode simulator?

Tags: html, css, scroll, mobile-application

Here's my code. There's a jQuery function on the button at the bottom which makes the list slide up into view (the list is blank here, it's populated by javascript. Here it's just blank lines, as you can see.)

The list slides up into view from right above the button and stop when it hits the Home div at the top. I can then scroll through the list while the button and the home div stay fixed at the top and bottom of the screen. On the simulator, anyway. On the ipod, once the list pops into view, when I scroll down, the home div and the button move upwards with everything else as if they were elements in the list! What the heck?

This is a mobile app made with PhoneGap.

```
 <body>

        <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; border-bottom: 3px solid; z-index: 19; background:#FFFFFF; padding:5px;"> 
            <a style="text-decoration:none; z-index:20;" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px; height:400px;"></div>

        <div style="position:relative">

            <div id="resultsList" style="background: #FFFFFF; width:100%; margin-top:15px; height: 400px; z-index:1; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; display:none">

                <br id="top"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/>
                <hr class="filler"/>
                <br class="filler"/> 

            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; border-top: 3px solid; z-index: 19; background:#FFFFFF; padding:5px;"> 
            <button id="bottombar" type="button" style="z-index:20; padding-bottom:5px;">Show as List</button>
        </div>

        <!--Maps API Key
         AIzaSyD52tRfTY1FtEgXQpvu9-jN5AOz-2pxQg0
         -->

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how they some smartphones deal with position: fixed, they move when you scroll then snap back.

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) might help you implement your style in a way that doesn't go nuts

Comment: No, you misunderstood a little. It doesn't scroll then snap back. The button and the home bar at the top *literally become list elements*, by all appearances. They just scroll right along with everything else. They do not snap back. I'll check out jQuery mobile.